# PostgreSQL TO_DATE query issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, to-date

I have the following PostgreSQL query:

```
INSERT INTO persoane_alocate(pa_id_pj,pa_id_corespondent_persoana,pa_procentaj,pa_tip_persoana,pa_data_inceput,pa_data_sfarsit,pa_afisare_in_monitor,audit_data_modificarii,audit_id_utilizator) VALUES ('670', '534', '0', '1', CASE 0000-00-00 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE TO_DATE('30 Nov -0001', 'YYYY-MM-DD') END, CASE 2007-02-12 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE TO_DATE('12 Feb 2007', 'YYYY-MM-DD') END, '2', '2012-03-20 17:11:34', 9999)
```

And I get the following error:

```
Query failed: ERROR: invalid value "Fe" for "MM" DETAIL: Value must be an integer.
```

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect the epxression `CASE 2007-02-12 WHEN 0` to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```
to_date('12 Feb 2007', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

instead of:

```
to_date('12 Feb 2007', 'DD Mon YYYY')
```

So you're trying to parse date using wrong format. See [the reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html).